# Display multiple video using Tkinter in python

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

I want to display multiple video from IP address in a GUI (atleast 4), below is my code, also there is lot of lag in the video, please help me with that also, i dont how to use Tkinter

```
import cv2
import imutils

vid1 = cv2.VideoCapture("url")
vid2 = cv2.VideoCapture("url")
vid3 = cv2.VideoCapture("url")

while True:
        ret , frame = vid1.read()
        ret1 , frame1 = vid2.read()
        ret2 , frame2 = vid3.read()

        frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=720)
        frame1 = imutils.resize(frame1, width=720)
        frame2 = imutils.resize(frame2, width=720)

        if (ret):
            cv2.imshow('cam0',frame)
            cv2.imshow('cam1',frame1)
            cv2.imshow('cam3',frame2)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
            break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: there is no `tkinter` code in the provided sample, and you can't really use `tkinter` for displaying videos, it is too slow for that (and you can't even optimize that because all `tkinter` stuff has to happen in one thread, in one process and that stuff is what takes the longest), theoretically if you wanted to optimize video displaying stuff you could split that into multiple processes but that won't work with tkinter and updating will still be a bottleneck at that point

Comment: if you know any better alternative than tkinter then please tell